# How to update fsspec in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use the Pandas `read_csv` method. Everything was working fine. I saved everything and started to work on it the next day but then I kept getting this error:

```
ImportError: Pandas requires version '0.7.4' or newer of 'fsspec' (version '0.6.2' currently installed)
```

I have updated pandas to the latest version twice to make sure that it is up to date. I am unsure what to do to troubleshoot going forward, any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Just do on command prompt

```
pip install  fsspec=0.7.4
```

It will work fine.

Comment: == instead of =

Answer (score 0):

You would need to install [fsspec](https://pypi.org/project/fsspec/)==0.8.2 (or a newer version than 0.6.2) in your project to continue working with pandas